# shorter way to check value and assign on TRUE

Tags: javascript, logic, variable-assignment

I'm not sure if it's *possible*, but is there a more concise (or faster way) to do the following?

```
if(w > width) width = w;
```

I'm working on a project that does similar logic **thousands** of times per second, but it's often more complex so I'd like to 1) make it faster if *possible* and 2) find a shorter way to write it for my own sanity.

** EDIT **

an example of something a bit longer

```
if(Math.abs(x) > this._boundingBox.width) this._boundingBox.width = Math.abs(x);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would at least be shorter to type:

```
width = Math.max(w, width)
```

Comment: using Math.max is the slowest to process per jsperf: http://jsperf.com/is-gt and although I'm going to stick with the if/else I like your innovation the best.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ternary operator:

```
width = (w > width ? w : width);
```

However, this may be slightly inefficient since it will assign `width = width` when the condition is false.

I'd still suggest you stick to the original code, though. There's no reason to obfuscate your logic.

Comment: This has a different result. I guess that you meant `width = w > width ? w : width;`.This solution, however, is not shorter than the OPs current state.

Comment: @RobW - Yeah, sorry, that was a typo. You're correct in it not being *shorter*, but I can't count the number of times I've seen a question like this where the accepted answer is *not* actually shorter than the question asked, just because they happen to prefer the alternative syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much faster this is though it seems more concise.

```
(w > width) ? width = w : w = w ; 
/* The w = w does nothing though a statement is needed */
```

I am also assuming you are using c or c++ since you require speed.

Answer (score 0):

try this (not tested):

```
w>width&&width=w;
```

and for other short-cuts, here's a quick reference:
http://geogeeks.net/2011/01/javascript-shorthands/

Comment: **Error**: `invalid assignment left-hand side`. You have to add parentheses around the last part of the expression. Surprisingly, the code didn't get shorter...